# create different dataframe based on field value in Spark/Scala

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a dataframe in below format with 2 fields. One of the field contains code and other field contains XML.

```
EventCd|XML_VALUE

1.3.6.10|<nt:SNMP>
      <nt:var id="1.3.0" type="STRING"> MESSAGE </nt:var>
       <nt:var id="1.3.9" type="STRING">AB-CD-EF</nt:var>
       </nt:SNMP> 
1.3.6.11|<nt:SNMP>
      <nt:var id="1.3.1" type="STRING"> CALL </nt:var>
      <nt:var id="1.3.2" type="STRING">XX-AC-EF</nt:var>
      </nt:SNMPe
```

Based on value in code field I want to create different dataframe conditionally and place the data in corresponding hdfs folder.

if code is 1.3.6.10, it should create message dataframe and place files under ../message/ HDFS folder and if the code is 1.3.6.11, it should create call dataframe and write data into call hdfs folder like ../call/

I am able to create the dataframes using multiple filter options but is there any option to call only one dataframe and corresponding HDFS write command.

Can someone suggest how can I do this in spark/scala please.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think the only way to achieve your result is what you are already doing: apply two different filters on your input dataframe and save the two results one after each other in HDFS

Comment: Thanks @werner. the challenge is I have around 30 events so looking for an option to make this as simple. Will let you know if I come across any solution